# List the equivalence classes of the relation R.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $X = \{−3,−2,−1,0,1,2,3 \}$.

Define the relation $R$ on the set $X$ by
$sRt$ if $s−t$ is even
for all $s, t ∈ X$.

The classes that I found
$ \{ -1, -3, 3\} $
$ \{ -1, 1, -3\} $
$ \{ 0,2,-2 \} $

But they are wrong, why?

UPDATE:
$ \{ -1, 1, -3, 3\} $
$ \{ 0,2,-2 \} $

Comment: Hint: Since equivalence relations are transitive the equivalence classes shouldn't overlap.

Comment: @DMcMor Thanks for the HINT. I have updated my answer with UPDATE. Can you help me check.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: That's correct.